# WaveShare e-Paper HAT button covers

Tags: hat, eink

I have a [WaveShare 2.7inch E-Ink display HAT for Raspberry Pi](https://www.waveshare.com/2.7inch-e-paper-hat.htm) that includes 4 buttons.

They work very well, but I was wondering if there was a "standard" way to add some sort of cover to them so I can add labels or unique colors?

[image: image description here]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question fits the 3D printing world to a Tee. My search efforts found different 3D printed cases to fit other e-ink products, but not one specifically designed for your model.

One may be able to locate a 3D printed Pi case that can be modified by a qualified designer to fit your HAT and incorporate the buttons, along with modification allowing for slip-in legends to match the buttons.

Reddit has a pair of subreddits aimed for people desiring to have custom designs [created](https://www.reddit.com/r/3Drequests) and/or [printed](https://www.reddit.com/r/3Dprintmything), if you are unable to locate a "perfect-fit" model and/or do not have access to a 3D printer.

I may have found one specific to your model, as it appears to have the buttons in the correct location, on [Thingiverse:](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2915631)

[image: Waveshare 2.7 eink 3D printed case]

Image from linked site.